# Starting Akka actors in Play

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, akka

I have a Play! application with some tasks I need to run periodically. I can schedule the tasks using Akka, but I am not sure how to start the scheduler itself. What I am doing right now is having a Scheduler object and starting it from `Global.scala`, like this

```
// app/jobs/Scheduler.scala
package jobs

import akka.util.duration._
import play.api.libs.concurrent.Akka
import play.api.Play.current

object Scheduler {
  def start() {
    Akka.system.scheduler.schedule(0 seconds, 1 minutes) {
      SomeTask.start()
    }
  }
}
```

and then

```
// app/Global.scala
import play.api._
import jobs.Scheduler

object Global extends GlobalSettings {
  override def onStart(app: Application) {
    Scheduler.start()
  }
}
```

The problem is that in this, the task runs even in development mode and during tests, that becomes soon very annoying.

> Is there a way to schedule jobs with Akka only in production mode?

Comment: There are methods `isProd`, `isDev` and `isTest` on [Play](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.1-RC1/scala/index.html#play.api.Play$) object to find out mode you currently running.

Comment: Thank you. While the methods you mention depend on having an implicit `app` in scope - which is not the case, since the argument to `onStart` is not implicit - following your link, I actually found that one can simply check app.mode, which does the same. If you want to put that into an answer, I will be glad to accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Methods `isProd`, `isDev` and `isTest` on [`Play`](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.1-RC1/scala/index.html#play.api.Play%24) object could be helpful. Even if you doesn't have implicit `Application` in scope, you can pass it explicitly

```
override def onStart(app: Application) {
  if (isProd(app)) Scheduler.start()
}
```